# Order by condition for two DATETIME columns 

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I read [ORDER BY condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367457/order-by-condition) and [How to add condition in 'order by'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213270/how-to-add-condition-in-order-by) but these don't answer to my issue.

I have 2 datetime columns called `CREATION_DATE` and `UPDATE_DATE`.

I want to sort (using `ORDER BY` clause) by :

- `CREATION_DATE` if `CREATION_DATE = UPDATE_DATE`

  or
- `UPDATE_DATE` in other case.

I wrote

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
ORDER BY
CASE Table1.CREATION_DATE
    WHEN Table1.CREATION_DATE = Table1.UPDATE_DATE THEN Table1.CREATION_DATE
    ELSE Table1.UPDATE_DATE
END ASC
```

but it does not work, I get an error at the `=` symbol.

I tried with other operators... Of course, I make mistake but I don't know if is correct to use operators in `WHEN` statement.

Is not accepted operators in `WHEN` ?

Thank you

Comment: Um, if Creation Date = Update date, then why is this not equivalent to just sorting by Update date?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

```
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN Table1.CREATION_DATE = Table1.UPDATE_DATE
     THEN Table1.CREATION_DATE
     ELSE Table1.UPDATE_DATE
END ASC
```

or simpler

```
ORDER BY Table1.UPDATE_DATE ASC
```

since you want to order by `UPDATE_DATE` only if it is equal to `CREATION_DATE`. In that case you could order by `UPDATE_DATE` too. In other cases you want to oder by `UPDATE_DATE`. So just only order by that. It is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ORDER BY UPDATE_DATE, CREATION_DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
ORDER BY
CASE 
    WHEN Table1.CREATION_DATE = Table1.UPDATE_DATE THEN Table1.CREATION_DATE
    ELSE Table1.UPDATE_DATE
END ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++ / java / C# 'analogy', the SQL `Case` statement can be used as both a `switch()`, and an `if / elseif / if` construct.

e.g. both of the following are legal:

```
declare @flag bit
set @flag = 0
select case 
    when @flag = 1
        then '1 selected'
    else
        '0 selected'
    end
```

And

```
declare @flag bit
set @flag = 0
select case @flag
    when 1
        then '1 selected'
    else
        '0 selected'
    end
```